# nginx not serving static files for django, searching in an other folder

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am deploying my django project to server using Nginx and Gunicorn static files are not loading.

2023/11/07 05:17:42 [error] 68970#68970: *40 open() "/home/pau/perp2.0/perp/staticfiles/static/admin/js/core.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)

The nginx is searching the file in /home/pau/perp2.0/perp/staticfiles/static/
but the directory for the static files is just /home/pau/perp2.0/perp/staticfiles without the last static

my file configuration for nginx is this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_ip;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/pau/perp2.0/perp/staticfiles;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

and just in case my settings.py for the static files part is this:

```
`# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../static'),
)

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage"
)`
```

I just one to serve the static files in the correct directory, thanks. If you can explain, the solution, will be great.

Comment: It should be `alias`, not `root` then. Note, trailing slash must match in `location` and `alias` definition.

Answer (score 0):

`root` means that *location* is under defined *root* path, that's why it is treated as a subfolder. If `/static/` is not a subfolder then you should use `alias` instead of `root`:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/pau/perp2.0/perp/staticfiles/;
}
```